# Rust invalid pointer with Box::from_raw() Box::into_raw() round trip

Tags: memory, rust, ffi

I'm banging my head against this supposedly simple usage of Box whilst trying to create some FFI helper code.

The sample here seems to give an error of `free(): invalid pointer` when used with a struct that has a field.

```rust
pub struct Handle(usize);

impl Handle {
    pub fn from<T>(obj: T) -> Self {
        let boxed = Box::new(obj);
        let mut ptr = Box::into_raw(boxed);
        Self::from_ptr_mut(&mut ptr)
    }

    pub fn from_ptr_mut<T>(ptr: &mut T) -> Self {
        Self(ptr as *mut T as usize)
    }

    pub fn to_box<T>(self) -> Box<T> {
        let obj: *mut T = self.to_ptr_mut();
        unsafe { Box::from_raw(obj) }
    }

    pub fn to_ptr_mut<T>(self) -> *mut T {
        self.0 as *mut T
    }
}

#[allow(dead_code)]
struct Crashes { value: u64 }

impl Drop for Crashes {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        println!("Crashes dropped");
    }
}

fn crashes() {
    let t = Crashes { value: 12 };
    let a = Handle::from(t);
    let b = a.to_box::<Crashes>();
    drop(b);
}

struct Works;

impl Drop for Works {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        println!("Works dropped");
    }
}

fn works() {
    let t = Works;
    let a = Handle::from(t);
    let b = a.to_box::<Works>();
    drop(b);
}

fn main() {
    works();
    crashes();
}
```

You can paste this into https://play.rust-lang.org/ and see how it throws aborts with the error `free(): invalid pointer`

The drop function seems to be called at the appropriate time, but the pointer seems to be somehow invalid

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You end up creating a double pointer here:

```rust
impl Handle {
    pub fn from<T>(obj: T) -> Self {
        let boxed = Box::new(obj);
        let mut ptr = Box::into_raw(boxed);
        Self::from_ptr_mut(&mut ptr)
    }

    pub fn from_ptr_mut<T>(ptr: &mut T) -> Self {
        Self(ptr as *mut T as usize)
    }
    ...
}
```

`Box::into_raw` returns a pointer, but then you take a mutable reference to that pointer, and store that address as a `usize`. You should just be using the `*mut T` as returned by `Box::into_raw`.

The reason that the non-working code with the double pointer compiles is that your `from<T>` and your `from_ptr_mut<T>` can take entirely different `T` parameters. If we consider the type `T` passed to `from<T>` to be a concrete type, then in this case you're calling `from_ptr_mut<U>` (where `U` is `*mut T`) with an argument of type `&mut *mut T`.

It should look like so:

```rust
impl Handle {
    pub fn from<T>(obj: T) -> Self {
        let boxed = Box::new(obj);
        let ptr = Box::into_raw(boxed);
        Self::from_ptr_mut(ptr)
    }

    pub fn from_ptr_mut<T>(ptr: *mut T) -> Self {
        Self(ptr as usize)
    }
    ...
}
```

[Working example in the playground.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3074946142a2eaec1808ac8544b94c4e)

---

Even though we are in the realm of `unsafe` you can have the compiler do some of the work for you by making the parameter `T` be bound to your `Handle` struct. This way you will be statically prevented from loading a different type than was stored.

[Playground example where Handle includes a PhantomData.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=8a6d84f0ac122081354c104aa05fbfdd)

In this second example you don't have to tell the compiler which item you're retrieving a la `a.to_box::<Crashes>()`, which is good because you  can't introduce undefined behavior by specifying the wrong type.